# Test Flex/Facebook Application localy

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, flash-builder

I´m new in Flex.
I'm trying to develop a Web Application integrated with Facebook.
I´m using Flash Builder 4.5 and the Adobe Facebook SDK.
The problem is that to test the application I need to upload the files to my webserver to avoid the facebook error.
I guess this is because Facebook only allows to run the application inside the domain that informed at my app page on Facebook.

Someone knows how can I test the application locally?

Best, Flávio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to test your application is to create a copy of your app on Facebook (i.e. register a new application), but set it up to point to localhost (i.e. your local development server). This will let Facebook send all the login redirects back to your local webserver rather than your current 'live' website.

It would help if you install a localhost webserver on your machine so you can run code locally. This will allow you to test your files on your own machine rather than having to upload them every time.

Comment: Thanks Niraj, I installed IIS and point my APP on Facebook to localhost. Works!

Answer (score 2):

Set up a local web server (I like Apache, but IIS will work).  with a virtual server and give it the same domain name as your production server.  Use a hosts file to point the domain back to your own server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Charles to record the web traffic, then build mock services that will provide that information.